# LibGDX how do I get a depthbuffer from FrameBuffer?

Tags: java, libgdx

now I'm working at a depth of field shader.
Here's how it works:

I render the whole scene to a FrameBuffer then apply the shader on it.
But, there's a problem: How do I pass the depthbuffer as an uniform to the shader? I couldn't find it anywhere in FrameBuffer's methods.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a LibGDX user (I use LWJGL), but in OpenGL you need to pass framebuffers as textures to a shader.  In LibGDX, `FrameBuffer` extends `GLFrameBuffer`.  In order to get the depth texture of a FrameBuffer, you need to call `getDepthBufferHandle()`, then treat it as you would a texture.